# No provider for servce 'VehicleService'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am getting the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for
>   VehicleService!  Error: No provider for VehicleService!  at
>   injectionError
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12066:90)
>   at noProviderError
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12104:12)
>   at ReflectiveInjector_.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:13546:19)
>   at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:13585:25)
>   at ReflectiveInjector*.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:13517:25)
>   at ReflectiveInjector*.module.exports.ReflectiveInjector_.get
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:13386:21)
>   at resolveNgModuleDep
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:20430:25)
>   at NgModuleRef_.module.exports.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21512:16)
>   at resolveDep
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22015:45)
>   at createClass
>   (C:\Users\andrewkp\source\repos\Complexus.Inventory.UI\Complexus.Inventory.UI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21868:35)
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for VehicleService! 
>   Error: No provider for VehicleService!

Here is my component making use of the VehicleService:

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { VehicleService } from '../../Services/VehicleService';
import { Vehicle } from '../../Models/Vehicle';

@Component({
    selector: 'addVehicle',
    templateUrl: './add.component.html'
})
export class AddComponent {
    @Input() public vehicle: Vehicle;

    constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService) {
        this.vehicle = new Vehicle();
    }

    public AddVehicle(): void {
        this.vehicleService.AddVehicle(this.vehicle);
    }
}
```

My VehcleService:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Vehicle } from '../Models/Vehicle';
import { ConfigService } from './ConfigService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {

    constructor(private httpClient: Http, private configService: ConfigService) { }

    public AddVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle) {
        try {
            //do some manipulation: CylinderCapactiy = Enginesize / CylinderVariant
            vehicle.CylinderCapacity = vehicle.EngineCapacity / vehicle.CylinderVariant;
            var response = this.httpClient.post(this.configService.AddVehicleEndPoint, vehicle);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

And my app.browser.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { VehicleService } from './Services/VehicleService';
import { StatService } from './Services/StatService';
import { ConfigService } from './Services/ConfigService';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        HttpModule,
        Http
    ],
    providers: [
        StatService,
        ConfigService,
        VehicleService,
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

And here is my app.shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { AddComponent } from './components/Vehicle/add.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AddComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'add-vehicle', component: AddComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: vehicle component belongs to which module ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye I updated my original question.  It belongs to NgModule

Comment: @Vikas What do you mean

Comment: check if the VehcleService is mistakenly provided in two modules ?

Comment: try importing VehicleService to your root module.

Comment: @RayLuxembourg Is it not enough to add it to NgModule

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your component registered under declarations in your app.browser.module.ts

if it belongs to the same module, add the component under providers as,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent]
})
```

if its from different module, add it under declarations and exports too. Also use **`HttpClientModule`** instead of **`Http`**

**EDIT**

As i mentioned above you need to add AppComponent under declarations and exports inside **`Shared.Module.ts`**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  exports: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: There is no mention of a `VehicleComponent` in the question. How does this answer the question?

Comment: VehicleComponent is supposed to be the component in which you call the VehicleService

Comment: @AmadouBeye in the post the service is getting used in the `AppComponent`. Am I missing something? The `VehicleService` is where the issue seems to be.

Comment: @R.Richards OP have not mentioned the name of the component earlier, updated it

Comment: @Sajeetharan Now this is making more sense. Thank you!! I thought I was losing my mind. :)

Comment: @monstertjie_za what's not working? check the sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pflu86?file=src/app/share/header/header.module.ts

Comment: I am getting confused between browser.Module, server.module and shared.module.  What is supposed to go where ?

Comment: create a stackblitz, the information provided in the question is not enough